# how to extract Json data without having a query in Retrofit

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, mobile-development

When I was having an Api Key then I used the following below code to extract the Json data from it.

Now I want to fetch Json data from https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchanges and I don't have any Api Key or query to pass.How can I do it using RetroFit?

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.create
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.Query

const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"
const val API_KEY = "5f60ae62gcbc4bdaa0d15164d7f1275b"

interface NewsInterface {
    @GET("v2/top-headlines?apiKey=$API_KEY")
    fun getHeadLines(@Query("country")country:String): Call<News>

}

object NewsService {
    val newsInstance :NewsInterface

    init {
        val retrofit: Retrofit= Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()

        newsInstance = retrofit.create(NewsInterface::class.java)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You API fun should be as,

```
@GET("api/v3/exchanges")
fun getExchanges(): Call<Response>
```